# "The page isn't redirecting properly" using redirect in .htaccess wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect

I’m trying to rewrite the url from `example.com/sub/sub1` to `example.com/sub1` and remove the `/sub/` path every time there is a `/sub1` next to it.

My solution redirects to `example.com/sub1` properly, but I am getting a loop redirect with the error message:

> The page isn't redirecting properly.

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /sub(/.*)sub1 $1sub1
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks, guys.

Edit: should be **RedirectMatch 301 /sub(/.*)sub1 $1sub1**

Comment: Are you sure that it is redirecting to `/sub1` properly? The `.htaccess` file you posted should only redirect to `/sub`, not `/sub1`.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add 1 at the end of the line. @WillS

Answer (score 0):

You should use redirects for specific pages, but if you want to redirect a whole subdirectory, you should be using rewrite rules instead. Using your example, you should have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$/sub/sub1/(.*)$ /1sub1/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Tried this, RewriteRule ^/sub(/.*)sub1$ $1sub1 [R=301,NC,L] still no luck :(

Comment: I updated my answer for you, that should work but let me know if it doesn't :)

Comment: still no luck mate i'm already trying to fix this the whole day lol :'(